# Different results with query api vs. hql

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following entity in hbm.xml file

```
<class name="Base" table="base">
    <id name="id"/>
    <list name="ips" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <cache usage="read-write" include="all" />
        <key column="base_id" />
        <list-index column="ip_order"/>
        <element column="ip" type="string"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

i have one entity Base with two ips string in the collection. 

when i make:

```
session.createCriteria(base.class).list();
```

the result is two Base object 
when i make:

```
session.createQuery(" from Base").list();
```

the result is one entity Base.

can someone tell me why i have this situation?

Comment: In your criteria `session.createCriteria(base.class).list();` should be `Base.class` (name must start with uppercase letter `B`). Does this just a misprint in your question?

Comment: No , because this is was only A spelling error

Answer (score 0):

As per your mapping xml `Base` is one table and `ips(IP)` is another table.

**One Base having two List(ips)** means `Base` table will have one entry in `DB(base table)`.
`IP` will have two entries in `DB (ip table)`.

Obvisully Base table will have only one entry.

Check this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_list_mapping.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I bet there are 2 records in the table for `ips`.

As you have declare `ips` being eager fetched, so it will also join fetch the `ips` when you are creating the criteria to fetch `Base.class`, causing the "result set" contains 2 records.  However, the two "records" are in fact same instance.

The way to solve is simple though, search for use of DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY result transformer.